# Stop reload application when orientation changes

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I need my app to not reload when the orientation changes. I have a regular portrait and a seperate landscape layout that both have the same stuff on the screen. But when I check a checkbox and change layout, it's no longer checked. Or when a checkbox has the number 5 in it  and then change layout it goes back to it's default number 1. How can I make it stop reloading?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a way to persist data between the two screens.

Either use savedInstanceState or ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

The checked state of a CheckBox and text in an EditText will be automatically preserved if you make sure they have the same `id` in both layouts. However, it only automatically preserves the things that can be changed through the UI, so if you programmatically changed the text of a CheckBox, that is not automatically preserved. Typically, that sort of thing is handled with a ViewModel and LiveData/Flow.

This behavior is controlled by the [`saveEnabled`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setSaveEnabled(boolean)) property of a view, which is true by default.

Answer (score 0):

add this following permission for your activity in Manifest file **android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize**

Something like this

```
<activity
        android:name=".YourActvity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
```

Comment: this does resolve the problem for us, but it gives us a new problem. We have a landscape xml file for our activiy so that the app is styled for landscape mode. But the buttons are not styled correctly anymore after we implemented this code

Comment: I think in your case you should create separate UI one for portrait and one for lanscape

Comment: @Masum They already explained that they created two layouts in their original question.

Answer (score 0):

First tip from Philipp Lackner explains how to use the savedStateHandle
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0d5ax97Mb30

The state when you change orientation, for example, gets restored, so you need to handle via viewmodel the state persistence.